# Jenkins pipeline not able to open a file

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying a pipeline script in which I need to open a file and change some text in . So my script goes like this :import java.io.File

```
node {
    stage('File settings') {
        dir ('gitfile') {
           dir('config') {
               sh 'dir'
               sh 'pwd > outFile'
               curPath = readFile 'outFile'
               echo "The current date is ${curPath}"
               def file = new File("${curPath}/"+"const.js")
                def lines = file.readLines()
                println "${file} has ${lines.size()} lines of text"
                println "Here is the first line: ${lines[0]}"
                println "Here is the last line: ${lines[lines.size()-1]}" 
           }

        }
    }
}
```

But I get error like :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Daily/smoke/config
/const.js (No such file or directory)
```

But the file is present in that location. Please let me know why this error happens.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the readFile() and writeFile() Jenkins pipeline steps to manipulate file contents on the workspace directory. See https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/